# Nested row fluid grid not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 5 dropdrowns and a column on right corner arranged horizontally in a same row. In the next row I would like to have few more dropdowns but I am not able to position in properly as the column on the right is width 500px;

```
    Example:

        ---------   ---------   ---------   ---------   ---------   
        dropdown1   dropdown2   dropdown3   dropdown4   dropdown5   column
        ---------   ---------   ---------   ---------   ---------   ---------
                                                                    |  Ads  |   
                                                                    |       |
        >I want to have a drop down here                            |       |
        ---------   ---------   ---------   ---------               |       |
        dropdown1   dropdown2   dropdown3   dropdown4               |       |
                                                                    |       |
                                                                    |       |
                                                                    |       |
                                                                    |       |
                                                                    |       |
                                                                    |       |
                                                                    |       |
                                                                    |       |
                                                                    ---------
        But its getting positioned here >>
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
<div class="starter-template">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                                <button class="col-sm-10 btn btn-sm btn-default">Search Job</button>

                                <button class="col-sm-2 btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                                <button class="col-sm-10 btn btn-sm btn-default">Search Employer</button>

                                <button class="col-sm-2 btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                                <button class="col-sm-10 btn btn-sm btn-default">Search Referee</button>

                                <button class="col-sm-2 btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                                <button class="col-sm-10 btn btn-sm btn-default">Job fair & Events</button>

                                <button class="col-sm-2 btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                                <button class="col-sm-10 btn btn-sm btn-default">My RTH</button>

                                <button class="col-sm-2 btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reason 4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-2 ad-block-right text-center" style="width:210px; height: 500px; border: thin black; border-style: dotted">
                            Advertisements
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--@@@@@@@@@@@@@ NESTED ROW NOT WORKING @@@@@@@@@@@--> 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="starter-template">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="">Search all jobs</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you please provide a snippet?

Comment: This is expected. Your structure does not fit the intended purpose. You shoud have two columns in the master row, one `-10` and a second `-2`. Then lay out your dropdowns inside the `-10`row`.

Comment: @GeethW Check the preview here http://plnkr.co/edit/SsKrtV5cIJVI5wHCYfuC?p=preview

Comment: @Paulie_D But I have tried with nested row inside row-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure is not right. First use `row`, then inside `row` separate with `col-sm-8` and `col-sm-4` (here ads column). And inside `col-sm-8` use `row` to separate rows of dropdrowns

```
<div class="starter-template">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                                    <button class="col-sm-10 btn btn-sm btn-default">Search Job</button>

                                    <button class="col-sm-2 btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                                    <button class="col-sm-10 btn btn-sm btn-default">Search Employer</button>

                                    <button class="col-sm-2 btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                                    <button class="col-sm-10 btn btn-sm btn-default">Search Referee</button>

                                    <button class="col-sm-2 btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                                    <button class="col-sm-10 btn btn-sm btn-default">Job fair & Events</button>

                                    <button class="col-sm-2 btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                                    <button class="col-sm-10 btn btn-sm btn-default">My RTH</button>

                                    <button class="col-sm-2 btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Reason 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--@@@@@@@@@@@@@ NESTED ROW NOT WORKING @@@@@@@@@@@--> 
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="starter-template">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="">Search all jobs</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 ad-block-right text-center" style="width:210px; height: 500px; border: thin black; border-style: dotted">
                            Advertisements
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic skeleton you need:

```
<div class=row>
   <div class=col-md-10>
        <div class="row">
            <div class=col-md-2>
                dropdown1
            </div>
            <div class=col-md-2>
                dropdown2
            </div>
            <div class=col-md-2>
                dropdown3
            </div>
            <div class=col-md-2>
                dropdown4
            </div>
            <div class=col-md-2>
                dropdown5
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class=col-md-2>
                dropdown1
            </div>
            <div class=col-md-2>
                dropdown2
            </div>
            <div class=col-md-2>
                dropdown3
            </div>
            <div class=col-md-2>
                dropdown4
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class=col-md-2>
   // your ads here
   </div>
</div>
```